# Spark Resource Allocation: Number of Cores

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Require understanding on how to **configure Cores for an Spark Job**.
My Machine can have a max. of `11 Cores , 28 Gb memory` .
Below is how I'm allocating resources for my Spark Job and it's execution time is `4.9 mins`

```
--driver-memory 2g \
--executor-memory 24g \
--executor-cores 10 \
--num-executors 6
```

But I ran through multiple articles mentioning number of cores should be ~ 5, when I ran job with this configuration it's execution time increased to `6.9 mins`

```
--driver-memory 2g \
--executor-memory 24g \
--executor-cores 5 \
--num-executors 6 \
```

1. Will there be any issue keeping Number of Cores close to Max. value (10 in my case) ?
2. Are there any benefits of keeping No. of Cores to 5 , as suggested in many articles ?
3. So in general what are the factors to consider in determining Number of cores?

Comment: Total 10 cores and you set 10 cores to the execute then only one executor can be there but how did you set it to 6?

Comment: I have multiple Nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the behaviour of job, one config does not optimise all needs.

`--executor-cores` means no of cores on 1 machine.

It that number is too big (>5) then the machine's disk and network (which will be shared among all executor spark cores on that machine) will create bottleneck. If that no is too less (~1) then it will not achieve good data parallelism and won't benefit from locality of data on same machine.

`TLDR`: --executor-coers 5 is fine.

Comment: Thanks Samir , that i understand but my job is running fine and taking less time with Cores=10. That's why i wanted to understand if keeping Cores to 10 is fine or there are any additional factors that i should consider as I'm new to Spark. Because if I reduce No. Of Cores Job will take more time. Why to keep Cores ~5 when I have a total of 11.

Comment: Seems like yours is a very simple job which does not do much shuffle and does not spill much data on disk (hence cores per executor = 10) is working fine. You should not consume all cores of a machine with spark as there are other crucial processes running on machine (like OS kernel processees) which you should not starve.